# Keycloak - Grant validation failed. Reason: invalid token (wrong ISS)

Tags: node.js, express, openid, keycloak, keycloak-services

So I'm having some issues with getting my Keycloak-Connect sample to work.

Basically I have a simple check with Keycloak on an express route On my VM

(10.10.10.54:8081) as follows.

```
app.get('/api*', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Hit API Backend!',
}));
```

My Keycloak Server is on a separate VM (for this example http://keycloak.myexternaldomain.ca/auth/)

the calls I've been making to test this out are.

```
RESULT=`curl --data "grant_type=password&client_secret=mysecret&client_id=account&username=myusername&password=mypassword" http://keycloak.myexternaldomain.ca/auth/realms/TEST/protocol/openid-connect/token`
```

This returns the proper access token everytime,

```
TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`
```

To parse token into a variable.

```
curl http://10.10.10.54:8081/api -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"
```

Which still constantly returns Access Denied, I tried this in a similar example with the [Keycloak-Quickstart Node Service](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs) to see if there was a more verbose error in that. What i'd receive back was

```
Validate grant failed
Grant validation failed. Reason: invalid token (wrong ISS)
```

Though if I waited a little bit it'd give me an Expired Token error so I feel like i'm on the right track.

so obviously there is something wrong from where i'm issuing the token from not matching where it's expecting? I can make a call to get the Users credentials from the keycloak server itself by cURLing to

```
curl --data "grant_type=password&token=$TOKEN&client_secret=secret&client_id=account&username=myaccount&password=mypassword" http://keycloak.myexternaldomain.ca/auth/realms/TEST/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

am I misinterpreting how I am supposed to be using Keycloak, or is this a settings issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My Issue was in my keycloak.json ... I had a different realm vs the one I was authenticating for.

If you're ever having this issue I suggest modifying [keycloak-auth-utils](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-auth-utils) to give you more verbose error logging on the grant-manager.

Specifically changing

```
else if (token.content.iss !== this.realmUrl) {
      reject(new Error('invalid token (wrong ISS)'));
}
```

to

```
else if (token.content.iss !== this.realmUrl) {
      reject(new Error('invalid token (wrong ISS) Expecting: '+this.realmUrl+' Got: '+token.content.iss);
}
```

helped me track down this issue myself.

Comment: I created the pull request here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-auth-utils/pull/80

Comment: I had this issue, and this answer led me to the problem. I had spaces in the Realm Name

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me to sort out my issue, one extra `/` !

Comment: The exact file and line number is https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/main/middleware/auth-utils/grant-manager.js#L427

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced with same issue . i used following checks to solve this

1.check the configuration in your project

- is serverurl exact (127.0.0.1 , localhost, 0.0.0.0 are different urls ..mention
  same as keycloak url)
- is realm  in small case
- is client id and secret is correct

if still you are facing a problem try to use single quote instead of double quote
*ex-*

`realm_name:"demo-realm"  --> realm_name:'demo-realm'`

it is working for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in localhost and getting the same problem, my issue was that I was using https in localhost, i.e `realmUrl: "https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master"` instead of `realmUrl: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master"`